# Use @apply or input global tag

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Why use this in the global css:

```
input {
  @apply w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 border-b-black p-2; 
}
```

If i can just do this?:

```
input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

(Im kinda new in tailwind world, sorry if is ""a dumb question"")

Comment: the second one is a vanilla css rule..and it's styling all input elements with some css properties. The first one requires to be processed before being fed to a browser because the `@apply` directive isn't strictly css. Anyway it's a totally different approach. Those utility classes (`w-full`, `rounded-md`,..) are styles that can be applied to any element having them among their own classlist. So you can quickly style a document without strictly touching the css props directly. But the point here is the `@apply` directive that applies those classes to the elements matching the `input` selector

Comment: as to why using one instead of the other... the first one is easier to mantain. You can quickly change the class list, it's easier to read because you don't have to be aware of which css props are addressed to give a given trait

Comment: Thks, i was thinking in that way.